# How to Jest mock fs.mkdir promisified function

Tags: reactjs, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, es6-promise

I am trying to implement mock for fs.mkdir promisified function. I searched for the answer in other threads, but sadly there is not a single solution for promisified one. Please let me know if this has been previously answered.

Here is my code (application.tsx):

```
...othre lines of code

const mkdir = promisify(fs.mkdir);
try {
      await mkdir(`${path}`, { recursive: true });
    } catch (error) {
      logger.debug(`in mkdir error ${error}`);
    }

...othre lines of code
```

I have this mock written (application.spec.ts):

```
jest.mock('fs');
jest.spyOn(fs, 'mkdir').mockImplementationOnce((func) => '');
```

When I am running this test file, my test cases fail at `await mkdir` call. I wanted it to just sail though all lines of code. So I am trying to implement a mock function which will resolve to true. But apparently, I am wrong here.
Any help is greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See the signature of `fs.mkdir()` method:

```
export function mkdir(
    path: PathLike,
    options: MakeDirectoryOptions & {
        recursive: true;
    },
    callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, path?: string) => void,
): void;
```

You should mock it to satisfy this signature.

The below example shows how to get the `fs.mkdir()` method to execute with an error. The `callback` of `fs.mkdir()` is an error-first callback, we pass the mock error as its first argument.

`index.ts`:

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
import fs from 'fs';

export async function main(path: string) {
  const mkdir = promisify(fs.mkdir);
  try {
    await mkdir(`${path}`, { recursive: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`in mkdir error ${error}`);
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { main } from '.';

describe('77843773', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'mkdir').mockImplementationOnce((path, options, callback) => {
      callback(new Error('mock error'));
    });

    const errorLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation();
    await main('./tmp/a/apple');
    expect(errorLogSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('in mkdir error Error: mock error');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77843773/index.test.ts
  77843773
    √ should pass (2 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.726 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package version:

```json
"jest": "^29.7.0",
```